# how to tell gcc to maximum optimize build for target platform only?

Tags: gcc, optimization

I plan to use my application only on one computer, which I use to compile it. What would be the easiset way to tell gcc to apply all possible platform-specific optimizations?

Assuming that I have Xeon E5 v1 PC should I just add `-march=core-avx-i` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095818/93647)? Or I should do more  / something else?

I'm using RHEL 7, gcc 4.8.2

Comment: `-march=native` tells to compile for this platform.

Comment: thanks, if this enough or I should add some more options?

Comment: It is in addition to all the usual, `-O3`, etc.

Comment: Try `-march=native -Ofast -funroll-loops`.

Comment: @Zboson it's interesting. is it safe to use these options? why they not enabled by default? what else options should I use? probably someone can summarize and can get complete and verified list of options.

Comment: `-Ofast` might not be "safe". It allows floating point math to be associative which breaks IEEE rules. It means the result may be different on different hardware. If this is a problem for you then use `-O3`.